# Posting Data to Multiple Columns into Mysql Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, arduino

So I'm trying to send 3 data values from an Arduino Mega to MySQL database using PHP for my senior design project but I'm encountering an issue. I found an example doing this with 1 data value that would also timestamp the data as it was received. For the life of me I can't figure out how to change the PHP code to pass through 3 values into 3 columns. Here is the PHP script for one data value being sent through:

```html
<?php

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
 if ($key == "yourdata") {
  $yourdata = $value;
 

}




// Check Connection to Database
if (mysql_connect($localhost, $username, $password))
  {
   @mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to select database");

    // Next two lines will write into your table 'test_table_name_here' with 'yourdata' value from the arduino and will timestamp that data using 'now()'
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename VALUES ($yourdata)";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  } else {
   echo('Unable to connect to database.');
  }

?>
```

And this is what I thought would work for 3 values but just doesn't end up working:

```html
<?php

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
 if ($key == "yourdata") {
  $yourdata = $value;
 }
        if ($key === "yourdata1"){
  $yourdata1 =  $value;
 }

 if ($key === "yourdata2){
  $yourdata2 = $value;


}


   

// Check Connection to Database
if (mysql_connect($localhost, $username, $password))
  {
   @mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Unable to select database");

    // Next two lines will write into your table 'test_table_name_here' with 'yourdata' value from the arduino and will timestamp that data using 'now()'
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename(yourdata, yourdata1, yourdata2) VALUES ($yourdata, $yourdata1, $yourdata2)";
   $result = mysql_query($query);
  } else {
   echo('Unable to connect to database.');
  }

?>
```

I tried testing by entering the address in the URL like so

```html
http://hydrosen.byethost11.com/insert_mysql1.php?yourdata=23&yourdata1=43&yourdata2=555
```

Like I said if I try it with one data value it works but it doesn't for three values. The table's column names are "yourdata" "yourdata1" and yourdata2".
Any help with this frustrating issue would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you putting your mysql credentials in the posted code?!!

Comment: Cause I forgot to take it out haha

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$yourdata = "";
$yourdata1 = "";
$yourdata2 = "";

foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key == "yourdata") {
        $yourdata = $value;
    }
        if ($key === "yourdata1"){
        $yourdata1 =  $value;
    }

    if ($key === "yourdata2){
        $yourdata2 = $value;
}

// Next two lines will write into your table 'test_table_name_here' with 'yourdata' value from the arduino and will timestamp that data using 'now()'
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tablename('yourdata', 'yourdata1', 'yourdata2') VALUES ('$yourdata', '$yourdata1', '$yourdata2')";
```

Comment: can u explain what happens? any error? missing values? wrong input?

Comment: Hey I managed to get it to work with the help of a friend but thanks for the help!

Comment: Great. post your own solution here and mark that as an answer. happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Okay here goes. Connect.inc.php has credential info and functions .php just routes the data to another table I believe.I'm not sure if all this is necessary to post the data but my friend wrote all the additional code and we've been busy trying to get the rest of the project to work so I haven't gotten a full understanding of how this works yet.

```
<?php
//ob_start();
include_once 'functions.php';
include_once 'connect.inc.php';
$id =2; // Id of sensor
$yourdata = "";
$yourdata1 = "";
$yourdata2 = "";
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key == "yourdata") {
        $yourdata = $value;
    }
        if ($key === "yourdata1"){
        $yourdata1 =  $value;
    }

    if ($key === "yourdata2"){
        $yourdata2 = $value;
}
$tot_data= $yourdata.','. $yourdata1.','.$yourdata2.';';}
//$tot_data= $yourdata.','. $yourdata1.','.$yourdata2.';';
if ($select_stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT `sensor_id`, `wifidata` FROM `wifi` WHERE `sensor_id` = ? ")) 
    {
//$id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $select_stmt->bind_param('d', $id);
        $select_stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
            $res = $select_stmt->get_result();
                if($res->num_rows==0)
        {
            if ($insert_stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO 
                `wifi`(`sensor_id`,`wifidata`)
                VALUES(?,?) ")) 
            {
```